# Bash : Get the current browser tab

Tags: bash, shell, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Is there any way to get the current opened tab in a browser (firefox at least) using bash .
In other words, the url of the tab that called the bash script from the file browser (incorporated in that page)

Comment: When you say "the tab that called the bash script", it is unclear to me what you are talking about. How does a tab "call" a bash script in your system?

Comment: I mean by "call" : Imagine a webpage where there is a file browser to select an application .
(In the bash script I am telling the system to open a url of another website where one of its parameters is the url of the current tab)

Comment: I am not sure if I am clear or not, but to make things very simple :
I would like to know if I can use xdotool or any other tool to get the url of the active tab of a web browser)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox changed the way it stores urls on the hard drive in version 33.

I wrote this php script to search for opened tabs. I used php, so you'll need php5-cli (or newer) package installed.

You'll need to ajust the $displayOnlyLastActiveUrl to fit your needs: set to false to display all opened url, true for last active opened URL

the script might need to be improved, but it fits my needs.

known limitations:

- migth not look in the good profile if you have multiple profiles set in firefox.
- might takes up to 10 seconds to update
- if you choose to output all urls, some closed tabs may appear

just create a php file with the above content and run it within shell  with `php yourfile.php`

```
<?php
//
// Display curent opened URLs in firefox.
// Author: Julien Marin (malinuxtele[AT]tuxfamily[DOT]org)
// Licence: GPL 3
//

$displayOnlyLastActiveUrl=true; //set to false to display all opened url, true for last active opened URL

//Search for restore.js (might need to be improved for multiprofiles environement...)
if (!$profileIniContents=fopen(getenv("HOME")."/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini", "r")) trigger_error("unable to open profiles file", E_USER_ERROR);
$profile="";
$ar_match=array();
while ($ligne=fgets($profileIniContents))
    if (preg_match("/Path=([^.]*)[.]default/", $ligne, $ar_match))
        $profile=$ar_match[1];

//Open recovery.js file
if(! $recoveryFileHandle=fopen(getenv("HOME")."/.mozilla/firefox/$profile.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js", "r")) trigger_error("unable to open recovery.js file", E_USER_ERROR);
$recoveryData=json_decode(fread($recoveryFileHandle, 4000000), true);

//parse data
$ar_tabs=array();
foreach ($recoveryData["windows"] as $actWindow)
    foreach ($actWindow["tabs"] as $actTabGroup)
    {
        $lastAccess=$actTabGroup["lastAccessed"];
        foreach ($actTabGroup["entries"] as $actTabEntry)
            if(!$displayOnlyLastActiveUrl) echo($actTabEntry["url"]."\n");
            else $ar_tabs[$lastAccess]=$actTabEntry["url"];

    }

//search last URL
if ($displayOnlyLastActiveUrl)
{
    ksort($ar_tabs);
    echo array_pop($ar_tabs);
}

?>
```

Answer (score -3):

I've found this by chance :

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in "$@" 
do
    #
    #
done
```

$@ contains the url of the tab.

Comment: please give proper answer . how can be use this